# Google Sheets to Google Data Studio - Year Comparison Combo Chart

Tags: google-sheets, looker-studio

I'm very much a beginner to Google Data Studio. I've been tasked with moving over our monthly reports from Google Sheets to the more attractive Data Studio.

I'm stuck on what I assume is actually a very simple chart but I just cannot seem to be able to recreate it. Would anyone be so kind to advise, please?

1. This combo chart is in the current Sheet:

   - X axis: Sales
   - Series: 2019, 2020
   - **Sales Combo Chart - Year vs Year**:
     [image: sales combo chart - year vs year]
2. It uses data from a table with the following set up (example figures):

   - **Table - Year, Month, Sales columns**:
     [image: Table - Year, Month, Sales columns]
3. The best I can create in Data Studio is a bar chart:

   - Dimension: Month
   - Breakdown Dimension: Year
   - Metric: Sales
   - Sort: Year
   - Secondary Sort: Sales
   - **Sales Bar Chart - Year vs Year**:
     [image: sales bar chart - year vs year]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Created a [Google Data Studio Report](https://datastudio.google.com/reporting/acf727d0-eb11-493b-ad7a-1dc50f3f01a1) (replicating the Google Sheet) to demonstrate with a **3 step process below**:

### Step 1: Date YYYYMMDD

Create a `YYYYMMDD` Date field at the Data Source-level; this can be achieved by using the [`CONCAT`](https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/7583443) function to consolidate the `Year` and `Month` fields and then adding a Day value (using `15` to represent the 15th day in the formula below) and combining the [`TODATE`](https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/7037300) function to create a Date format recognised by Google Data Studio:

- ***Name***: `Date YYYYMMDD`
- ***Formula***: `TODATE(CONCAT(Year, Month, "15"), "%Y%b%d", "%Y%m%d")`
- ***Type***: Date (YYYYMMDD)
- ***Optional***: Disable the `Month` and `Year` fields

**GIF to visualise Step 1**:

[image: 4]]

### Step 2: Date Range

Add a [Date Range Control](https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/6291067) and set the range to Advanced:

- ***Start Date***: Today Minus 1 Year
- ***End Date***: Today Minus 0 Year(s)

**GIF to detail step 2**:

[image: 6]]

### Step 3: Chart

Add a [Time Series](https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/7059697) Chart with the following:

- ***Date Range Dimension***: `Date YYYYMMDD`
- ***Dimension***: `Date YYYYMMDD`

  - ***Granularity***: `Month`
- ***Breakdown Dimension***: `Date YYYYMMDD`

  - ***Granularity***: `Year`
- ***Metric***: `Sales`
- ***Breakdown Dimension Sort***: `Year` in Descending order
- ***Style***:

  - ***Series no. 1***: Bars
  - ***Series no. 2***: Line; ***Show Points***: Select

**GIF to explain Step 3**:

[image: 8]]

### Step 3 (Alt): Chart (Comparison Date Range)

Added a [New Page to the Report](https://datastudio.google.com/reporting/acf727d0-eb11-493b-ad7a-1dc50f3f01a1/page/j2JJB) to provide an alternative approach that uses a [Comparison Date Range](https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/9272806) in a Time Series Chart:

- ***Date Range Control***: This Year
- ***Dimension***: `Date YYYYMMDD`

  - ***Granularity***: `Month`
- ***Comparison Date Range***: Previous Year

**GIF to elaborate on expand on Step 3 (Alt)**:

[image: 11]]